# compare current date with another dateTime on javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a date returned from database in this format "2013-05-27 14:27:37" and i need to compare this date with the current date.

everytime i tried to parse my date it returned invalid date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox doesn't allow that format.  Use either `/` instead of `-`, or use a `T` instead of a space separating the date and time components.  See [this chart](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html) for details.

You might consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  You can parse a string to a moment like this:

```
var m = moment("2013-05-27 14:27:37", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Then you can use moment's comparison functions. For example:

```
if (m1.isBefore(m2)) { ... }

if (m1.isAfter(m2)) { ... }
```

You can read [the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/) for additional functions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always parse it manually.

```
var s = "2013-05-27 14:27:37";
var m = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/.exec(s);
var date = new Date(+m[1], +m[2] - 1, +m[3], +m[4], +m[5], +m[6]);
```

Comment: This seems tom be worked with me, but i wonder why i couldn't do it with new Date(); it would be easier, right? any way thank you for the smart solution.

Comment: Very nice. :)  As far as a direct parser for this specific format, it doesn't get much better than this.

Comment: @ahmedsaber111: The only format that `new Date` [is required to support](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.4.2) is [(more or less) ISO 8601](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15). So you can’t rely on a browser to support anything else (like in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var date = new Date('2013-05-27 14:27:37');
```

That should give you a valid `Date` object to work with in your js.

Comment: Gives “Invalid Date” on Firefox.

Comment: gives invalid date, and this is what i did before and i don't know what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also try pasring your date via [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/category/tutorial/) ,hope this helps.

Comment: If you're using date.js, be sure to use the maintained fork. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info).

Comment: @ahmedsaber111 - date.js modifies the `Date` prototype.  You could load it from require, but it doesn't scope as you might expect.  Moment.js on the other hand does support AMD directly, and doesn't modify the `Date` prototype.